Running LaCie SSD 4 Tb on Linux 22 onwards
I'm looking at a LaCie 4tb SSD - not a hard drive - to run on ubuntu 22. It says it runs out of the box on Mac and Windows. Can I plug and play with Ubuntu? If not what will I need to do?

Ubuntu 22??  So you want to use it on Ubuntu Core 22?  (22 being the reduced version of 22.04).  The device itself matters less in my opinion, but more what's on it is what I consider; ie. what partition table, what file-systems are involved... eg. if the system was from a non-PC (non-standard partition table or NO partition table) or even a BSD system there maybe more involved.  I suggest you work out what is on the device & then you'll know what you need to do.

FYI:   Ubuntu Core 22 is the specialist version of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server, being a reduced function version that is faster to spin up on Cloud Servers, using less RAM useful for IoT devices etc... so it'll do most of what 22.04 will do, but some differences may apply. As 22 will not use deb packages; this will impact 3rd party packages you can include for example (22 being the snap only version of 22.04)
